# Stack Overflow social network analysis

Tags: discussion, social-networking

Has a social network analysis visualization been done using tools such as [Gephi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gephi)? If yes, can I see some examples?

Comment: SO isn't a social network, so how can you do a social network analysis on it?  There's no concept of "friends" or even really linkages of any type.

Comment: for example, visualizing users - users via questions and answers asked.

Comment: Just because the focus isn't social does not mean that there isn't a social component. Why else have chat? Visualizing a relationship between askers and answerers would be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

I've just released [an application which converts Stack Exchange data dumps to GraphML](https://github.com/CraigStuntz/StackGraphMl), which Grephi can read (though the Stack Overflow data is large enough that Gephi struggles with it -- but igraph in R works fine). Have at it!